# Best way to perform MySQL queries in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

What is the most correct way to perform MySQL Queries using PHP?

I read *somewhere*, that instead of using the old mysql_connect/mysql_query() statements, we should be using something else now! And the person who wrote that made it sound like we all should have known this by now.

I'm no expert on this stuff, but I really can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays most applications are developed using an ORM like doctrine or propel. Internally most of them are using PDO....

Answer (score 2):

[mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) are recommended nowadays, mainly because they support parametrized queries which, if used properly, eliminate the risk of mySQL injection.

Comment: Okay, awesome :) Thanks for the links. So, in order to use MySQLi, does my existing hosting people have to support it, or are the requirements for mysqli the same? If you know what i mean?

Comment: @Lucifer see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.requirements.php it's usually available by default, but check with your provider first.

Comment: Thanks for the requirements link - I just checked on winhost, they do support it :D - Thanks for your help!

Comment: *if used properly*, old good mysql eliminates risk of injections as well. And also saves you one database call

Answer (score 1):

improved mysql (myqli) or PDO ?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) over `mysql_*`. There are plenty of tutorials out there, e.g. [this one](http://www.pixel2life.com/publish/tutorials/1378/an_introduction_to_pdo/).